# yum install php-devel amongst other commands returning problems

Tags: php, centos

I run `yum install php-devel` and it returns this.  Typically I'd just run it with --skip-broken, but when I do, it still doesn't do the trick.

```
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-6)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
       Available: php54w-common-5.4.29-2.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.29-2.w6
       Available: php54w-common-5.4.30-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.30-1.w6
       Available: php55w-common-5.5.13-2.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.13-2.w6
       Installing: php55w-common-5.5.14-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.14-1.w6
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

When run with `--skip-broken` it returns this at the end:

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:

```
 autoconf-2.63-5.1.el6.noarch from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 automake-1.11.1-4.el6.noarch from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 pcre-devel-7.8-6.el6.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 php-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 php-cli-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 php-mysql-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 php-pdo-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 php-soap-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-6
 php55w-cli-5.5.14-1.w6.x86_64 from webtatic
 php55w-common-5.5.14-1.w6.x86_64 from webtatic
 php55w-devel-5.5.14-1.w6.x86_64 from webtatic
```

This problem has arisen with a few other similar commands when installing something related to php, except I've just done without them.

I need to install this for something I'm trying to do.  I do remember upgrading to PHP 5.4 and our entire infrastructure coming down due to it requiring PHP 5.3, so I downgraded as quick as possible to get everything back running and that may contribute to the issue.

If you have any idea why this is happening and how I could get the package on the system while remaining on PHP 5.3, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using content from the `webtatic` repository? If not removing it might help (though you might need to clean up the system a bit after that to get back to a known sane state.

Comment: I believe I switched to that when I upgraded then downgraded because I was looking for a quick solution.

Comment: How could I get rid of it?  Would this cause the infrastructure to go down? If so it's fine, I'll just do it late at night when there aren't users on.

Comment: Removing the repository itself will do nothing to the running system. It will, however, prevent further installation and updating of packages that were installed from that repo. Which you may or may not be using. I also don't know that the `webtatic` repo is part of the problem since is isn't clear to me exactly what yum thinks is wrong at the moment. (Can you include the full output from trying to install the package?)